# source_files in podspec when source code is organized into nested group folders

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec, code-structure

Under my framework directory, I have the codes organized into groups like-

```
myFramework- (git repository root folder)
        .git 
        LICENSE 
        README.md
        myFramework -
                      myFramework.podspec
                      podfile
                      myFramework.xcodeproj
                      myFramework - 
                                   Constants - .swift files
                                   extensions - .swift files
                                   view -
                                          view-model- .swift files
                                          custom views - .swift files
```

In this case where .swift files are nested under groups and sometimes the groups has nested groups which holds the .swift files, how can I set the source_files in podspec.
Currently, I have the following which is not working-

```
s.source_files  = "myFramework/**/*"
```

Can anyone please tell me, if there is a way to keep my code structure and specify the source_files in podspec, or do I really have to break the structure and put everything under

```
/myFramework/myFramework
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested structure for sources should be fine.

The podspec should be at the root of the repo to work in both development and deployment modes.

Comment: So, s.source_files  = "myFramework/**/*" will work, if my pod file is in the root folder? but shouldn't it be in the folder which holds .xcodeproj file?

Comment: The Podfile should be in the folder with an app's .xcodeproj. The podspec should be at the repo root.